# How to refer to a react file outside of its first parent directory (beyond ../)

Tags: reactjs, import, path

I'm working on my website with react, but the files were getting a messy so I wanted to organize them into further sub-folders. I've always imported components from the component folders using "../" but now that my components folder is further than the reach of ../ I assumed that all you had to do was refer to it again, like ../../ but it does not seem to be working.

**Files**

```
src > Components > Component1 (file)

src > Pages > ICS4U0 > ICS4U0_DS (file)
```

The goal was to import Component1 into the ICS4U0_DS file

I referred to import as: `import Component1 from '../../components/Component1';`

But I got the error message is

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../components/Component1' in '/Users/stephenni/portfolio/src/pages/ICS4U0/ICS4U0_DS'
```

When I refer to the import as: `import Component1 from '../../../components/Component1';`

I get the error message

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../components/Component1 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Help pls :D

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem might be coming from your exports in Component1 file, try Checking if Component1 has got a default export.

```
export default Component1
```

I hope this helps